# Adding event on JQuery toggled class

Tags: jquery, toggleclass

My markup:

```
<ul id="playerControls">
    <li class="play-bt"></li>
</ul>
```

And I have this event that fires if the play button is pressed:

```
$(".play-bt").bind('click',function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('pause-bt');
});
```

Now I am assuming that `play-bt` class name has been changed to `pause-bt`, but how come this event:

```
$(".pause-bt").bind('click',function(){
    console.log('PEW');
});
```

Is not being fired?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Now I am assuming that .play-bt class name has been changed to
>   pause-bt.

`toggleClass` doesn't work like that.

`toggleClass` is the combination of `addClass` and `removeClass`.

`toggleClass` will check whether the specified class exists.

- If it does, it removes it from the element.
- If it doesn't, it adds it to the element.

---

Regarding the reason your event does not fire, this is because you must have binded that click event **before** assigning the class `pause-bt`.

`bind()` searches for all elements which match the selector, *at that current point*, and assigns the function to the event handler.

You need to either rebind this event, or use `live()` instead of `bind()`

`live()`:

> Attach an event handler for all elements which match the current
>   selector, now and in the future.

http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: The use of .live() is no longer recommended. See this page for an explanation: http://www.jquery4u.com/jquery-functions/on-vs-live-review/#.UCKRWE3iY3g

Comment: @Faust thanks for that, good read! In which case I would recommend OP uses `on()`. Seeing the OP's comments I'd guess they need to update to jQuery 1.7 for this to work

Answer (score 3):

`.bind()` only captures elements that exist at the time.  Since your element didn't have that class initially, it was not bound. Depending on your version of jQuery, you want either `.live()` or `.on()`.

Comment: I've changed i to .on it is still not working. I am using the latest JQuery

Answer (score 0):

Because when you fist set the binding, the element you're targetting did not have that class. Use the jQuery .on() function and bind to the container like this:

```
$('#playerControls').on('click', '.pause-bt', function(){
      console.log('PEW');
});
```

The event will fire on #playerControls, at which point it will *then* look for .paust-bt